# Error when attempting to run application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-web-api

I am moving an asp.net web forms application over to mvc. I want to re-use as much code as possible so I decided use my existing linq to sql library.

I am new to MVC, but have viewed numerous videos from PluralSite for direction.

I created a model library to work between the linq to sql and the web api.  I had read that I needed to do this because of linq to sql's complexities.

I have also created a web api and started adding linq queries to the controllers.

```
public IList<Model.vSchedulesFill> GetCustomerSchedules(int id)
    {
        var sch = from p in _context.vSchedulesFills
                  where p.CustomerID == id
                  orderby p.SchedStartDateTime descending
                  select new Model.vSchedulesFill(p);

        return sch.ToList();
   }
```

I tested the above query using Fiddler and the result were good, so I tried to run the program and received the HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error.

The database is on a remote server, but I am running the app in debug mode on my local machine.

The error mentions no default document or IIS directory browser not turned on.

I looked up the default document and saw a lot about adding the web api help file.  So I went to NuGet and installed it, but the application still will not run.

I have looked all over for solution to this problem...

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to fix this?

Thanks for your help

Added

```
     <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
```

to web config under section system.webServer.

Can view directory but that's not what I needed.  I basically wanted to be able to run the program and then type in the path in the address bar, like I did in Fiddler.

I didn't remove any of the default layout forms included in the web api project.

Thanks

Comment: Just a remark. Think to designing API service in more restful way. Look here my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287313/what-would-be-more-restful-recommended-practice-for-flipping-a-boolean-via-patc/15287947#15287947. Regarding your problem - it might be also security on the api level, I do not know how do you have it configured? Do the debugger break in to this API action?

Comment: No it doesn't break.  I am almost ready to give up on the api with the view and make a repository with an mvc project.  What do you think?

Comment: Well there should be the purpose to expose this data through WebAPI, right? If there is no big reason it would be really better to skip this layer. However, I think you have problem with some kind of security. Thy to first debug in Global.asax on "BeginRequest" event. And inspect the request and the context ...

Comment: It appears it can't find the views.  I do get the directory list, and when I click on views I get a 404.

Comment: What do I check for security?

Comment: No, no you do not access directly here to the view like it was in ASP.NET. You have here a so called "middleman" a Routing, you should really check it out: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api. Regarding security ... First check web.config what do you have configured here, based on: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security.

Comment: I do have the routing setup.  I use the default api/{Controller}/{id} in webapiconfig.  When I tested with Fiddler the information was returned.  The starting project was a Internet MVC 4 app.  After reading about the web api, I removed the internet MVC app.  I am wondering if there is some setting that needs to be changed because of this removal.  I also checked web.config, but it is raw, I haven't added any security info.  Thanks

Comment: Its is hard to help like this, but I would recommend that you start again from scratch. And than slowly adding the your implementation. Of course make sure that it working from scratch as it should.